# MySQL/PHPMyAdmin - Importing 15,000 rows with 512MB of RAM

Tags: mysql, database, import, phpmyadmin, field

I'm trying to import 15,000 rows of data into my MySQL database. I know exactly how I would do this normally, but I have a constraint. 512MB of RAM... What's the most efficient way of doing this? Is there any way for MySQL to automatically import at a slower rate that way it doesn't crash due to not enough memory? Also, note that I'm using PHPMyAdmin. Thanks!

Comment: Does RAM really matter here? I think the insertion will be row-by-row, and you aren't going to need much RAM. Did you try this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big of each row? If 1k(which is already very big) each row, 15000 rows only 15M, I don't think this will be a problem. If you really worry about it, just insert one row each time, don't use a bulk insert.

Comment: its a 19-character VARCHAR for each of the rows so I'll try this out

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are using a VPS on something like Digital Ocean? If so then you can create a swap file:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04

or look around for how to create a swap file for your os / vps.

Hope that helps. Cheers

Comment: I guess I should mention that if you don't have ssh access then maybe something like this:
http://www.rusiczki.net/2007/01/24/sql-dump-file-splitter/

Comment: Or you might find is you do have ssh access and created the swap file, then importing might be better using the mysql command:
mysql -h localhost -u yourusername -p yourschemaname < yourlargesqlfile

Comment: Yeah Im using DO but on that page you linked in your original post, there's a warning about hardware degradation... :/

Comment: It looks like they really want you to upgrade to a $10 instance. I have been using a swap file on many of DO $5 instances without an issue for quite a while. The swappiness setting of 10 is for those rare cases like yours - a short period of time. For example, I am not able to finish installing certain node packages without it. However, that's the first time I have even heard of that warning. Thanks for pointing it out. However, personally, I would just use the swap file and make sure you backup often. It's a $5 instance so I am guessing you are not doing anything too mission critical :)